# jQuery preblems with click on nested created elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I created the below html with JavaScript and I want to be able to listen to the click on both the `channel_li` and `client_li`.

**Generated HTML**

```
<li cid="4" class="channel_li" style="display: list-item;">Random<ul class="client_ul">
    <li class="client_li" clid="14" style="">Hanekawa</li></ul>
</li>
```

The second code snippet is the JavaScript I'm using to generate the elements and assign a click event. The problem I have is that when I click the `channel_li` nothing happens, and when I click on the `client_li` it triggers the `channel_li` listener. Is there anyway of fixing this?

**JS**

```
// Some generation code here.

// $li here is the created channel_li element.
$($li).on("click", "li", function() {
    console.log("channel click");
});

// More generation code.

// $foo here is the client_li element.
$($foo).on('li', 'click', function () {
    console.log("client click.")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, becoue `$li` is not a variable or valid selector:

```
// $li here is the created channel_li element.
$($li).on("click", "li", function() {
    console.log("channel click");
});
```

for

```
// $li here is the created channel_li element.
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    console.log("channel click");
});
```

How you need trigger diferens events use the clase for:

```
// $li here is the created channel_li element.
    $(document).on("click", ".client_li", function() {
        console.log("Client click");
    });

// $li here is the created channel_li element.
    $(document).on("click", ".channel_li", function() {
    e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("Channel click");
    });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W68sa/)
[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/W68sa/2/)

> **Description** *stopPropagation:* Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of
>   the event.

Comment: When doing this it registers the click on the client_li correctly, but it also registers a click on all of the channel_li elements.

Comment: For that is the stopPropagation(); stop the channel and execute only Client, see the live demo.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but every time I click on one of the click channel_li elements it registers a click on all of them, and not just the one I click on. It works correctly when clicking on a client_li.

Comment: it's becouse the ´li´ controls are nested, and that create a tree in the DOM, executing all the tree controls. for that is stopPropagation();

Answer (score 1):

You will need stopPropagation(): http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/, because nested elements are in question.

```
$(document).on("click", "li.channel_li", function() {
    alert("channel click");
});

$(document).on("click", "li.client_li", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
    alert("client click");
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W68sa/1/

Comment: When doing this it registers the click on the _client_li_ correctly, but it also registers a click on all of the _channel_li_ elements.